# Rails: passing validations in rake populate rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a rake populate file to build dummy data.

```
@corp_page = CorporatePage.create(title: 'Home', static_descriptor: 'Home')
    @panel_count = CorporatePanel::PANEL_TYPE.count
    if @corp_page.title == 'Home'
         ----
    else
      puts "Corp Page not saved"
      puts @corp_page.inspect
    end
```

On inspect it appears my validations are preventing the instance being made. Why?

```
Freddys-MacBook-Pro:gll_corporate McGroarty$ rake db:populate
 not saved
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fdb2f5162f8 @base=#<CorporatePage id: nil, title: nil, static_descriptor: nil, workflow_state: "draft", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:title=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

The values are exactly as validated for. Why isn't this working?

## CorpPage model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: corporate_pages
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  title             :string(255)
#  static_descriptor :string(255)
#  workflow_state    :string(255)      default("draft")
#  created_at        :datetime
#  updated_at        :datetime
#

class CorporatePage < ActiveRecord::Base

    HOME_PAGE='Home'
    PAGE_TYPES=[HOME_PAGE]

    has_many :corporate_panels

    validates_presence_of :title
  validates :static_descriptor, inclusion: PAGE_TYPES
```

### Rails 4

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling a `save` after you have already called `create`? Do you want to call `new` instead of `create`?

Comment: Sorry, that shouldnt be there. it still does it without save.

Comment: Show us your CorporatePage model. Also, what rails version is?

Comment: This doesn't add up. Try using `CorporatePage.create!(...)` which will raise an error immediately if the create fails. Post the results of that back here. Because there is no way I can see for your `if` statement to evaluate to false. Even if `create` fails to *save* the CorporatePage instance because it is invalid, it should be setting the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails prevents mass assignment of variables by default

With rails 4, as far as I know, you can add this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

execute

```
bundle install
```

from the command line

and in your model put

```
attr_accessible :title, :static_descriptor
```

this way you're whitelisting the attributes you allow to be mass assigned.
Actually it used to be a default functionality but has been deprecated, I'm still learnng the new 'right way' :)

I would have commented as my answer is definitely missing a lot but I'm still not allowed to. (50 reputation to comment)

Comment: @giulp ia m using rails 4

Comment: Mass-assignment protection only applies when attempting to use params in a Controller. ActiveRecord, by itself, doesn't blink twice if you hand it a hand-rolled Hash like this.

Comment: awesome man. I just needed the attr_accessible, which i thought was depreciated. any way for the purposes of this it works. great